# Custom icon Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, customization, google-maps-markers

This map works fine, I just have one trouble.
I need to create a different icon for each marker.
I really don't have lucky with my codes ^^
how do I?

```js
var side_bar_html = ""; 
var gmarkers = []; 
var map = null;

/**
*map
**/

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.421409,-51.936722);
var marker = createMarker(point,"This place",contentString0)

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.421409,-51.934722);
var marker = createMarker(point,"This place",contentString1)

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.421409,-51.932722);
var marker = createMarker(point,"This place",contentString2)
```

//put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div

```js
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});
```

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window

```js
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
```

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function

```js
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

gmarkers.push(marker);
side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your marker constructor add an icon property with the icons URL to the anonymous object you're passing:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon:(image URL here),
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

(Send via mobile, sorry if layout is bad).

Comment: thanks, but doing this I change an icon for all markers. I need one different icon for each marker, that's the problem, ex: 
'var marker = createMarker(point,"This place",contentString0, **icon**)'

Comment: As per your example, pass the icon image path to the createMarker function via the icon argument then assign this to the icon parameter.